# Can ‘auto’ be used in a function declaration?

Tags: c++11, header-files, forward-declaration, auto, function-declaration

Background:

I found this handy random number generator and wanted to make a header file for it:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
auto dice = std::bind ( distribution, generator );
int wisdom = dice()+dice()+dice();
```

However, in C++11, a function declaration with return type ‘auto’ requires a trailing return type so the compiler can decide what the type is. 
E.g.:

```
auto foo(int a, int b) -> decltype(a*b);
```

Problem:

It appears like my header would need to be almost as long as the function itself to determine the type:

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
auto roll() -> decltype(distribution(generator));
```

Question:

Is there a way around determining the full return type for a function declaration (in a header) that uses the ‘auto’ type?
If not, what should my dice() header look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you use `int` as the template type for [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution), the return type of `distribution(generator)` is `int`. Unless the real code is templated as well, then the return type could be hard-coded to `int`.

And if the real code is templated then you can use the `result_type` member of [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution):

```
template<typename T>
typename std::uniform_int_distribution<T>::result_type roll();
```

Or simply the template type itself:

```
template<typename T>
T roll();
```

Comment: I agree that it should be `int`, but each time I try to use int, the compiler spits out `redefinition of 'dice' as different kind of symbol`, even though they should return the same type, so I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I needed to reformat the function from "std::bind" to int utils::dice() {return(distribution(generator));}